# Thailand and Vietnamese Characters not showing correctly after migrate to asp.net and SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, unicode, encoding

We have old asp website with SQL Server 2000 database. Some of the table stored Thailand and Vietnamese characters. These characters showing correctly in asp pages.

After we migrated to new asp.net with mssql 2008 database, these Thailand and Vietnamese characters are showing unknown characters and not readable in asp.net pages.

Both databases(2000, 2008) collation set to **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** and column are set as **NVARCHAR**.

Also both asp and asp.net page content type set to utf-8. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: You need to do more debugging yourself - you need to work out whether it's an issue with the application, or with the database. Use e.g. SQL Server Management studio to confirm whether the stored data is still correct. Then eliminate the one it *isn't* from the question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your comment, I did compare the two db result in Management studio 2008 data are same. But I what confuse is, Thai characters also not showing in result grid in Management studio, but i use this data to show in asp page its show correct Thai characters.

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is not on the DB you said?
you are sure the data on the database is fine?

how are you fetching the data to the UI? 
just a guess, but check the colation on the tempDb database. if you are using a temp table inside a procedure (very specific guess) the data would be ordered on the tempDb, if the colation is diferent, you may have issues.